# Indexing a list

Tags: python

```
from typing import List

def up_to_keyword(items: List[str], keyword: str) -> List[str]:
"""Return a new list that contains only the items that occur before keyword
in items, or all items if keyword is not an element of items.  Do not
include keyword in your result.
"""

    n_list = []
    if keyword not in items:
        return items
    else:
        for i in range(len(items)):
            if items.index(i) < items.index(keyword):
                return n_list.append(i)
```

How would I go about coding the case where the keyword exists in the list? Is my code close to satisfying the given conditions?

Comment: You could just use splicing of the list, which would be items[:items.index(keyword)]

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
for i in range(len(items)):                     
    if items.index(i) < items.index(keyword):
        return n_list.append(i)
```

To:

```
for i in items:                                  # Updated. You want the actual value not the index.
    if items.index(i) < items.index(keyword):
        n_list.append(i)                         # Updated. Don't return. Other elements might be remaining to add.
return n_list                                    # Added. Now everything is done. So, return.
```

Or:

```
return items[:items.index(keyword)]              # Does the same thing, using slicing. Pythonic way of doing it.
```

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:

```
def up_to_keyword(items, keyword):
    n_list = []
    if keyword not in items:
        return items

    return items[:items.index(keyword)]
```

Comment: What does it mean `IIUC`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the **List Comprehension** here. Try below code:

```
from typing import List
def up_to_keyword(items: List[str], keyword: str) -> List[str]:
    if keyword not in items:
        return items
    else:
        return [i for i in items if items.index(i) < items.index(keyword)]
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
from typing import List

def up_to_keyword(items: List[str], keyword: str) -> List[str]:
"""Return a new list that contains only the items that occur before keyword
in items, or all items if keyword is not an element of items.  Do not
include keyword in your result.
"""

    if keyword not in items:
        return items
    else
        items[:items.index(keyword)]      #List slice up to first occurance of keyword
```

No need of variable n_list. OR:

```
from typing import List

def up_to_keyword(items: List[str], keyword: str) -> List[str]:

    if keyword in items:
        return items[:items.index(keyword)]      #List slice up to first occurance of keyword
    return items                                 #No need of else
```